# Referencing a struct declared in a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

Alright, been at C++ for about 2 days now.  Just done javascript before...

I'm making a template queue using a linked list.  My compiler does not like it when I try to make a new Node struct from withink queue.cpp

```
//queue.h:
template <class Object>
class Queue
{
 public:
  Queue();                              // Default
  Queue(const Queue& original);         // Copy

  ~Queue();                             // Destructor

  const Queue& operator=(const Queue& rightHandSide);  //overloaded op

  bool isEmpty() const;

  bool enqueue(const Object& d);
  bool dequeue(Object& d);

 private:
  // Node definition
  struct Node
  {
    Object data;
    Node * next;
  };
  // Queue data members
  Node * front, * back;
};
```

So, in my copy contructor I need to make a new Node.

```
//queue.cpp
template <class Object>
Queue<Object>::Queue(const Queue& original)
{
  if (original.isEmpty()) {
    front = back = NULL;
  } else {
    front = back = new Queue::Node;                 //this is line 26
    front->data = original.front->data;
    Queue::Node * ptr = original.front->next;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
      back->next = new Queue<Object>::Node;
      back = back->next;
      back->data = ptr->data;
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }
  }
}

queue.cpp: In copy constructor âQueue<Object>::Queue(const Queue<Object>&)â:
queue.cpp:26: error: expected type-specifier
queue.cpp:26: error: expected `;'
```

Any help plz?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside member functions of `Queue`, you can refer directly to `Node`.

```
front = back = new Node;                 //this is line 26
```

and

```
Node * ptr = original.front->next;
```

What you have inside the loop will also work, where you explicitly specify the template parameters. However, note that since `Node` is private, unless you make the template instantiations `friend`s with each other, you must specify the template parameters for the current instantiation, so `Queue<Object>::Node` is fine, but `Queue<int>::Node` is not, apart from for `Queue<int>` itself.

Answer (score 1):

What's your compiler used? Your code shouldn't have any problem. Because when the name Queue is used inside the class, is equivalent to `Queue<Object>`.

It's in C++ standard,

> Like normal (non-template) classes,
>   class templates have an
>   injected-class-name (Clause 9). The
>   injected-class-name can be used with
>   or without a template-argument-list.
>   When it is used without a
>   template-argument-list, it is
>   equivalent to the injected-class-name
>   followed by the template-parameters of
>   the class template enclosed in <>.
>   When it is used with a
>   template-argument-list, it refers to
>   the specified class template
>   specialization, which could be the
>   current specialization or another
>   specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Once the copy constructor starts, `<Object>` will be implicitly added along with `Queue` whenever needed. For compatibility with all platforms you should declare like following:

```
front = back = new typename Queue::Node;  //this is line 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different suggestion:

```
// Node is defined within same "class { }", so it needs no "::" qualification
front = back = new Node;
```

In any case, your code as given compiles fine (http://ideone.com/UrLN0), so I wonder if there's something else outside what's here.

The identifier `Queue` with no template parameters refers to the current instantiation, inside the template itself.

Comment: In C++0x he needs `typename` before `Queue::Node` . The compiler you tried probably implements the C++0x meaning, which means you can leave it off.

Comment: @Johannes: If no `::` is used, no `typename` is necessary, right?